# Is it permissible to marry one's niece?

Tags: sharia, nikah

My maternal grandfather (grandfather) married two women and my mother was from the second wife and I have an aunt who is from the first wife of my grandfather. Now I am in love with a girl who is the daughter of my aunt's daughter. By relation she is my niece.

So is it permissible in Islam to marry that girl?

*Note: She is not my own sister's daughter but the daughter of my cousin's sister.*

Comment: In terms of the genetic material you share, it comes to something like 1/32 (an oversimplification, but w/e). From a genetics perspective, you're good.

Comment: If you're female, probably not.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you're incorrectly considering her to be your niece. She is the daughter of your cousin's sister (cousin too, I suppose). So neither your cousin, your cousin's sister nor your cousin's sister's daughter is your mahram.

Therefore you *can* marry the girl.

To answer the question in title. *No, one can't marry their nieces or nephews (niblings).*